# How can I switch scene by taping the screen in Cocos2d 3

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, game-physics, spritebuilder

I am making a game in Cocos2d & SpriteBuilder. *Is it possible to switch to a new scene by taping on the screen?* I know how to do it with a button.

So if someone out there can help me, that would be awesome!:)

Comment: this could use a generous helping of "here's what I tried"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it works the same way as for a button.  When you understand how to handle touches the implementation is very easy:

First turn on user interaction for the node that shall accept touches:

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
```

Then implement the `touchBegan:` method:

```
- (void)touchBegan:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // if you want to only react to touches in certain areas add check here
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] replaceScene:myScene];
}
```

For a basic introduction to touch handling in Cocos2d 3.0 read: https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/366/touch-handling-in-cocos2d-30